# Access VBA code combination not working, issue with exit sub?

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I'm very new at VBA and I can't seem to solve this problem. It seems like it should be an easy problem to fix, I just don't know how. I've looked around on the web, but the question remains unsolved.

So what the code does: In the main form is a record. This record will be copied to another table bij pressing a button on the form. Before the copying begins, the code checks first if the 'OMnummer' has been filled in in the subform. If not, a message box appears saying that the user should fill in the subform and the code stops running.

Secondly the code checks if the record is allready present in the other table. If so, a messagebox appears and the record will not be copied. If not, the record will be copied to the other table.

Both pieces of code work ok seperately. However, when I try to include both pieces in the same private sub, only the first one works. It may be something with the 'Exit Sub' code or I am not using the If - Then right.

Really hope you can help me! Monika

```
Private Sub KnopProjectVersturen_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrProc


'This is the first part of the code checking if the subform has been filled in

If IsNull(Me!Subform_OMnummers.Form!Omnr) Then
If MsgBox("Vul het OMnummer in. Je kan het project niet exporteren zonder OMnummer.")     Then
Exit Sub



'This is the second part of the code, checking if the record exists in the other table and then copying part of the record

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Qry_Depo_ControleAanwezig"
If DCount("Deponering.projectnummer", "Qry_Depo_ControleAanwezig") = 0 Then
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Qry_projectnaarDepot"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Qry_ToevoegProjectDepot"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Depot_uitvoer", , , "[Projectnummer] = '" & Me![Projectnummer] & "' And [subID]=[subID]"
    Me.Status = 8
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, ("Qry_Depo_ControleAanwezig")
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Else
    MsgBox "Dit project bestaat al in de Depot_Uitvoer, verander de status in het projectformulier", vbInformation, "Example"
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, ("Qry_Depo_ControleAanwezig")

End If
End If
End If



'Als er fouten zijn laat deze code een messagebox zien met het nummer en de melding.
 ExitProc:
 Exit Sub
 ErrProc:
 Select Case Err.Number
 Case Else
    MsgBox Err.Number & "--" & Err.Description
    Resume ExitProc
    End Select
 End Sub
```